# How to change the directen of .slideUp and .slideDown javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have a scroll-down menu which is sliding up from top but I want it to slide up from the bottom
This works but in the wrong direction:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
enableSelectBoxes();
});

function enableSelectBoxes(){
$('selectBox').hide();
$('div.selectBox').each(function(){
        $(this).children('span.selected').html($(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').html());
        $(this).attr('value',$(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').attr('value'));

    $(this).children('span.selected,span.selectArrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display') == 'none'){
            $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').slideDown(200);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').slideUp(200);
        }
    });

    $(this).find('span.selectOption').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().slideUp(200);
        $(this).closest('div.selectBox').attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
        $(this).parent().siblings('span.selected').html($(this).html());
    });
});             
}
```

But how can I change the direction of the slideUp and slideDown so it will scroll in from the bottom and scrolll out too bottom

```
slideUp -> display:none;
slideDown -> display: block;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Czjvn/1/

Comment: please create fiddle or plunker.

Comment: What happens if you change .slideDown(200); to .slideUp(200); and vice versa?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Czjvn/1/ here it is

Comment: @mplungjan that won't work